# UnicodeDecodeError happen with .p file(pickle)

Tags: parsing, unicode, pickle

I gave path of .p file and try to load the file.
But this error happened
"UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xf0 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)"

```
def main(params):

  # load the checkpoint
  checkpoint_path = params['checkpoint_path']
  print ('loading checkpoint %s' % (checkpoint_path, ))
  #with open(checkpoint_path, 'rb') as pickle_file:
  #    checkpoint = pickle.load(pickle_file)
  checkpoint = pickle.load(open(checkpoint_path, 'rb'))


if __name__ == "__main__":
  parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
  parser.add_argument('-checkpoint_path', default="D:\\neuraltalk\\cv\\flickr8k_cnn_lstm_v1.p", type=str, help='the input checkpoint')
  parser.add_argument('-r', '--root_path', default='D:\intermediate-cnn-features\images', type=str, help='folder with the images, tasks.txt file, and corresponding vgg_feats.mat file')
  parser.add_argument('-b', '--beam_size', type=int, default=1, help='beam size in inference. 1 indicates greedy per-word max procedure. Good value is approx 20 or so, and more = better.')

  args = parser.parse_args()
  params = vars(args) # convert to ordinary dict
  print ('parsed parameters:')
  print (json.dumps(params, indent = 2))
  main(params)
```

i tried to fix it doing like this.

```
with open(checkpoint_path, 'rb', encoding='utf-8') as pickle_file:
  checkpoint = pickle.load(pickle_file)
```

But the other error happend..
"ValueError: binary mode doesn't take an encoding argument"

what should i do?

Answer (score 0):

`pickle` is a binary protocol, so use binary mode.  As your error says, "binary mode doesn't take an encoding argument":

```py
with open(checkpoint_path, 'rb') as pickle_file:
  checkpoint = pickle.load(pickle_file)
```

Your other error "UnicodeDecodeError", would only happen in text mode.  Make sure to use `'rb'`.  If you still have issues, update your question with a reproducible example, along with sample input and a full traceback of the error message.

Full demo:

```py
import pickle

data = {'key':[1,2,3], 'key2':[4,5,6]}

with open('out.p','wb') as f:
    pickle.dump(data,f)

with open('out.p','rb') as f:
    data2 = pickle.load(f)

print(data == data2)
```

```
True
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer my own.

You can fix this problem by adding this code

```
with open(checkpoint_path, 'rb') as pickle_file:
      checkpoint = pickle.load(pickle_file, encoding='latin1')
```

Comment: Was the pickle file pickled by Python 2?  Documentation [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html#pickle.Unpickler) looks like what you found.

Comment: I'm just wondering how you created the .p file in the first place.  Normally the encoding wouldn't be needed.  Are you specifying a different pickle protocol than the default?  This is why it's important to make a reproducible example in the question, but the .p file wasn't provided.

Comment: I'm using a code from https://github.com/karpathy/neuraltalk. I got an .p file from traning and now i'm doing a "Using the model to predict on new images". but i can't use matlab. So i extract features by .npy and change to .mat.